# How can I make the prompt command output a semicolon in Oracle (TOAD)

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

Currently this statement (in TOAD)

```
PROMPT test;
```

outputs:

```
PROMPT test
```

I would like it to output:

```
PROMPT test;
```

Including the semicolon.

Can anyone recommend how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if these will work in Toad and I don't have a copy to try it on, but it seems to mimic SQL*Plus in a lot of areas - it doesn't seem unreasonable to think it's completely mimicking `prompt`.

Anyway, in SQL*Plus the semi-colon is being interpreted as a statement terminator. You could change the terminator:

```
set sqlterminator #
prompt test;
set sqlterminator ;
```

... or add an extra semi-colon:

```
prompt test;;
```

... or define a variable and use that to prompt:

```
define my_prompt = 'test;'
set verify off
prompt &my_prompt
```

None of these work in SQL Developer, and I'm not sure if Toad even supports substitution variables... so any or none of those might work for you, but gives you some things to try.

Comment: The first two did not work, however the last one does. Thanks!